# Collapsing a stream of multiple lines into one line

Tags: text-processing, newlines

I have a file containing a a large number of lines, each of which contains a bunch of numbers which are separated by spaces. I process this data in a pipe in some way, and then I want to collapse the multiple lines into a single line of all the numbers separated by spaces.

Is there a standard command-line utility I can use to do this? It seems like most line-by-line utilities won't mess with the newlines...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

That's why you don't use line-by-line utilities for this.

```
$ tr '\n' ' ' < input.txt > output.txt
```

Answer (score 4):

Even line-by-line utilities can remove all newlines.

sed:

```
sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/ /g' file
```

awk:

```
awk '{printf $0" "}' file
```

But it's much better to use `tr`, like @Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams wrote.

Comment: I knew it could be done with sed, but you're right, tr is better. Yet another two-letter unix utility to add to my belt.

Answer (score 0):

pipe the output to `xargs`

```
#!/bin/sh -x
while
do
date > temp
ping cp1za >> temp
cat temp | xargs echo
done
Tue Dec 17 18:23:31 UTC 2013 CS V1R12: Pinging host CP1ZA.TMMNA.TMM.TOYOTA.C (150.45.12.22) Ping #1 response took 0.001 seconds.
```